# Google Analytics, Events report is showing in Real Time but not in BEHAVIOR

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote below code for google analytics using `cocoapods`. When i click on `Button` in my App, Google Analytics showing Event report in Real time but when i Open `Behavior->Events->overview`, there is no `button` `event` report and showing zero hits.

Here is my code:

```
let tracker1 = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker   
tracker1.set(kGAIScreenName, value:"Home Screen")                                                         
let event =  GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("ButtonStatastics",  action: "Button is pressed",  label: clickButton.currentTitle,  value: nil).build()
tracker1.send(event as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Could you please let me know what can be the reason?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but you need to typically wait up to 24 hours for data to be processed into your standard reports, so you should wait a bit longer.

Comment: great , Thank you. i will wait

Comment: I could see the report after 24 hours. it working fine. Thanks

Comment: should wait 24 hours for crash and exceptions also ?

Comment: I don't know. Are you tracking those with events too? The 24 hour wait suggestion is only for GA hits.